# Value from input box is not getting incremented or decremented?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made 2 buttons one for increment and another for decrement but when I click on button + it does not increment value of the input box similarly it does not decrements the value from input box on clicking button -

main.js:

```
var currentvalue = document.getElementById("date").value;

console.log(currentvalue);


function increment () {
  var newvalue = parseInt(currentvalue) + 1;
  document.getElementById("date").value = newvalue;
}

function decrement () {
  var newvalue = parseInt(currentvalue) - 1;
  document.getElementById("date").value = newvalue;
}
```

index.html:

```
<body>

    <div id="center">
        <label for="name">Date</label>
        <p></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="plus" onclick="increment()">+</button>
        <input type="text" id="date" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onclick="decrement()">-</button>

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this `var currentvalue = document.getElementById("date").value;` inside the function because outside function it will execute only once during load and then the value will be set in it

```js
function increment() {
  var currentvalue = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var newvalue = parseInt(currentvalue) + 1;
  document.getElementById("date").value = newvalue;
}

function decrement() {
  var currentvalue = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var newvalue = parseInt(currentvalue) - 1;
  document.getElementById("date").value = newvalue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="center">
  <label for="name">Date</label>
  <p></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="plus" onclick="increment()">+</button>
  <input type="text" id="date" value="1">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="minus" onclick="decrement()">-</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Why I am getting reference error ? see this -> https://imgur.com/a/aKrKB

Comment: I have add main.js in html but still it shows reference error why so?

Comment: I have shared my html and js files above and also error which I am getting in previous comments

Comment: When I click on plus/minus button it shows reference error saying increment and decrement is not defined

Comment: are you correctly loading the main.js file? Check from network tab ,also this file should be loaded after loading jquery & bootstrap

Comment: This snapshots are not from network tab. Open chrome(for simplicity) open developers tool click on network tab and reload the page. Check if `main.js` is loading

Comment: You are not correctly loading the file . So is this error